# Can pytest_sessionfinish still call the fixture with session as scope?

Tags: pytest

I need call one fixture when all the tests are successful. I tried to check if all tests are successful in pytest_sessionfinish. I also put my fixture with the session scope @pytest.fixture(scope="session"). However, the code in pytest_sessionfinish can not call this fixture at all. Are there some way to solve this issue?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def myfunction(
    ser: Serial, logger: Logger
) -> bool:
    print("In my function")
...

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
   print("Prepare to call myfunction")
   myfunction
```

It only showes "Prepare to call myfunction" as the output.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the strict hook requirement? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to do some global teardown? You can do this in the fixture itself.

Comment: Thanks! In my use case, I first need wait all test cases finished. Then, based on the test results, for example all passed, I will need execute myfunction. It is the reason I introduced pytest_sessionfinish and this hook.  In myfunction, I want to access some objects defined in the fixtures. However, I found that in pytest_sessionfinish I can not access any fixture objects at all. What is the solution for such use case?